# ios upload file to amazon s3

Tags: ios, amazon-s3

I am working on an ios app that needs to be able to upload files to amazon s3 but I am having some issues. The function manages to create the correct key or path within the s3 bucket but the file itself does not upload into it. below is the code for 1 of the options i have tried

```
if (self.s3 == nil) {
        self.s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:[Config getS3Key] withSecretKey:[Config getS3Secret]] ;

    }
  [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(processBackgroundThreadUploadInBackground:)
                           withObject:params];

}


- (void)processBackgroundThreadUploadInBackground:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
{


    S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:@"staging/videos/" inBucket:@"aaa.aaaaa.com"];
    por.contentType = @"video/mp4";
    por.data        = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[params valueForKey:@"takeurl"]]];

//    por.contentType = @"image/png";
//    por.data        = [params valueForKey:@"takeimage"];


    S3PutObjectResponse *putObjectResponse = [self.s3 putObject:por];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showCheckErrorMessage:)
                           withObject:putObjectResponse.error
                        waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

this creates the key path staging/videos/ within the bucket on s3 but the file is not there. I tried this with an image file also. I have checked to make sure that the data that i am trying to push up is not nil.
The xml response i get from the server says that the content length is 0 though.
I have also tried the multi part approach from the s3 sdk with the same result.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: When using the AWS Java SDK, the documentation for the AmazonS3Client says that the Content-Length must be set. Perhaps this is something to check?

Comment: afraid setting the content length of the objectrequest to the length of the data didnt make any difference. thanks though

Comment: @glogic were you able to figure out the answer

Answer (score 3):

I'm obviously really late with this response, but just in case anyone else has this problem in the future, you were structuring your request wrong.

By doing:

```
S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:@"staging/videos/" inBucket:@"aaa.aaaaa.com"];
```

with a backslash at the end of your key, you were creating a folder, not a file. You need to end your key with the filename including a suffix, ex `@"staging/videos/video.mp4"`.

Comment: Yeah forgot to get back to this. That was the simple mistake on my part